# Error al ejecutar la función fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de copiar esta página pero me sale un error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\include\config.php on line 19

Éste es el código relacionado:

```
<?php
/* Dev EnigmaXml */


// CONFIGURACION PREDETERMINADA //


$host = "localhost";
$userhost = "root";
$pwhost = "trinity";
$db_web = "web_wow";
$db_auth = "world"; 
$facebookID = "290682684291199";
$foro = "#undefined";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $userhost, $pwhost, $db_web); 
if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo"Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.")".$mysqli->connect_error;
}
$config = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM configuracion");
$info = $config->fetch_assoc();
$configuraion_alert = "<p class='pull-right' style='color:white'><a href='https:' target='_blank'>Dev EnigmaXml</a></p>";
?>
```

Comment: Hola @Brahian, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Faltan muchos detalles en tu pregunta, es imposible poder ayudarte así. Tendrías que añadir más datos sobre con qué estas trabajando, el código completo, la estructura de tu base de datos... Echa un ojo a [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Además, no entiendo el "Estoy tratando de copiar esta página". ¿A qué página te refieres?

Comment: `$config` esta teniendo un valor de `FALSE` *(boolean)* porque el `mysqli::query()` te esta dando error en la consulta. Revisa la consulta a la base de datos, comprueba que la tabla esta creada correctamente.

Comment: Por favor, ejecuta `SELECT * FROM configuracion` directamente en tu BD y coméntanos los resultados.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro de que `configuracion` no existe en tu bbdd

Answer (score 3):

Eso se debe a que tu consulta devuelve el valor `false`.

Te recomiendo hacer una comprobación de la consulta para comprobar si te lanza un error y poder controlar este tipo de errores.

```
if ($config = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM configuracion")) {
    while ($info = $config->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Aquí tratas tus datos
    }
}else{
    echo "La consulta es errónea";
}
```